# natsort() not sorting alphabetically case insensitively in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, natsort

So I have 2 questions:

> 1. from what I understand natsort() is supposed to sort an array alphabetically case insensitively but once I compile the code below.

```
<?php
        function splitSort($sentence){
            $stringArray = explode(" ",$sentence);
            natsort($stringArray);
            for($i=0; $i<count($stringArray);$i++){
                echo $stringArray[$i] . ", ";
            }
        }
        splitSort("Hellod darkness hello My old");
?>
```

I get

> Hellod, darkness, hello, My, old,

where i thought I was supposed to get

> darkness, hello, Hellod, My, old

2. If the sorting was truly case insensitive and the expected result would occur if I change Hellod to Hello which hello would come first?

Comment: `natcasesort()` would be case insensitive.

Comment: Also I think you got confused with it, that it keeps the key association. So with your for loop you just loop through your array values :P Use `foreach` to loop through the sorted array, or reindex the array first. (Also do: `print_r($stringArray)` after your sorting :)

Comment: Thanks a lot solved my problem instantly

Comment: Also, I always look at the manual page and scroll down to **See Also** `natcasesort()` - _Sort an array using a case insensitive "natural order" algorithm_